# Quality of a signal

Tags: probability, signal-processing

Let's consider a signal y(t) that is an output of a linear transformation with the addition of noise.
$$y ( t ) = Ax ( t − \theta) + m ( t )$$

The hypothesis on the signals x(t), y(t) is that they are both:

- random stationary processes with finite variance
- random processes with zero mean value

I need to find out the power of the signal and noise components separately.

I multiply both members by $x(t-\theta)$ and average, obtaining (E = Expected Value, m(t) is not correlated with x(t), $\sigma^2_x$ is the variance of the input signal)
$$E [ x ( t − \theta ) y ( t ) ] = A E [ x ^2 ( t − \theta ) ] + E [ x ( t − \theta ) m ( t ) ] = A \sigma^2_x
$$

Hence $$^{(1)}A=\frac{1}{\sigma^2_x}E [ x ( t − \theta ) y ( t ) ]$$

A depends on $\theta$ but since $\theta$ is arbitrary we chose a $\sigma$ that gives the maximum value of A.

$$A_0 = \frac{1}{\sigma^2_x} max_{\theta}E[x(t−\theta)y(t)]= \frac{1}{\sigma^2_x} E[x(t−\theta_0)y(t)]
$$

We can therefore evaluate the power of the signal component:

$$^{(2)}S = A_0^2 E[x^2(t−\theta)]=\frac{1}{\sigma^2_x} \{E[x(t−\theta_0)y(t)]\}^2$$

The points $^{(1)}$ and $^{(2)} $ are both confusing to me.

The first one, I'm not sure why the scaling factor A is given by that formula.

The second one I'm not sure why or how the equality holds.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me break it down a bit more.   (Adding a $_\bullet$ after $A$ and $\theta$ as a reminder that they are co-dependent.)

$$\require{enclose}\begin{align}\mathsf E\big[x(t-\theta_\bullet)\,y(t)\big]=&~ \mathsf E\big[A_\bullet\, x^2(t-\theta_\bullet)+m(t)\, x(t-\theta_\bullet)]\big) 
& \enclose{circle}{1} &~y(t) = A_\bullet\,x(t-\theta_\bullet)-m(t) 
\\[1ex]=&~ A_\bullet\,\mathsf E\big[x^2(t-\theta_\bullet)\big]+\mathsf E\big[m(t)\, x(t-\theta_\bullet)\big] 
& \enclose{circle}{2} &~\text{linearity of expectation}
\\[1ex] =& A_\bullet\,\mathsf E\big[x^2(t-\theta_\bullet)\big] + 0 
& \enclose{circle}{3} &~ \text{x,m are uncorrelated}
\\[1ex] = & A_\bullet\,\sigma_x^2 & \enclose{circle}{4} &~\text{x has zero mean}
\\[3ex]\therefore~ A_\bullet =&~ \frac 1{\sigma_x^2}\,\mathsf E\big[x(t-\theta_\bullet)\,y(t)\big] 
&\enclose{circle}{5}&~\text{algebraic rearrangment}
\\[3ex]S= &~ A_0^2~\mathsf E\big(x^2(t-\theta_0)\big)
& \enclose{circle}6 & ~\text{given}
\\[1ex] =&~ A_0 \Big(A_0\mathsf E\big[x^2(t-\theta_0)\big]\Big) & \enclose{circle}7 &~ a^2b = a(ab)
\\[1ex] =&~ A_0~\mathsf E\big[x(t-\theta_0)\,y(t)\big] & \enclose{circle}8 &~ \text{refer to }\enclose{circle} 3\text{ above}
\\[1ex] =&~ \left(\frac 1{\sigma_x^2}~\mathsf E\big[x(t-\theta_0)\,y(t)\big] \right)\,\mathsf E\big[x(t-\theta_0)\,y(t)\big] & \enclose{circle}9 &~ \text{refer to }\enclose{circle} 5\text{ above}
\\[1ex]\therefore~ S =&~ \frac 1{\sigma_x^2}~\left(\mathsf E\big[x(t-\theta_0)\,y(t)\big] \right)^2 & \enclose{circle}{10} &~ (ab)b= ab^2
\end{align}$$

Are any steps not clear enough?